# Bootstrap accordion with ember

Tags: ember.js

Hi there i have a small question that belonging to my small ember application.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z63Ur/6/) upload is here. I used bootstrap accordion to visualize my tickets. When i click on the "click" it adds another accordion into my view. But sadly it cannot be opened or used. Every accordion i dynamically created cannot be opened or closed. There is no error or exception thrown and from my point of view everything should work fine. My click-function looks like this:

```
click: function() {
    this.counter++,
    name = this.name+this.counter.toString(),
    tre = App.Ticket.create({
        Text: "try",
       id: name
    });

    this.pushObject(tre);
}});
```

The belonging html is here:

```
<div class="accordion-group">
    {{#each content}}
       <div class="accordion-heading">
           <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" {{bindAttr href="id"}}>
                 Ticket ID/Störfall
           </a>
        </div>
        <div {{bindAttr id="id"}} class="accordion-body collapse in ">
             <div class="accordion-inner">
                 {{Text}}
             </div>
         </div>
     {{/each}}
</div>
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an action helper to the accordion link title

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-parent="#accordion2" 
{{bindAttr href="item.id"}} 
{{action "click" item target="view"}}>
     Ticket ID/Störfall
</a>
```

Then implement a click handler event in your view

```
   App.TicketView = Em.View.extend({
        click:function(context) {
            var el = this.$('a[href='+context.get('id')+']');
            el.toggleClass('collapsed');
            this.$('#'+el.attr('href')).toggleClass('in');
        }
    });
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z63Ur/13/)

Comment: Sorry ken but your fiddle is not working. When i add additional accordions they cannot be opened.

Comment: It fixed, it was because of the default value of the name of ActiveTab object #collapse. I also changed the name of the action name to prevent the event from bubbling up.

Comment: One last note, i commented out the third link you added manually. It should rather be part of the controller content, so that you loop through it and set the right item to the action helper.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ken. I really appreciate it. But i dont understand why my original code is not working. I cant see an error or anything